# Convolutional Neural Network weight keeps growing during training

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, conv-neural-network

I am training a CNN. The whole training process works well. Now the loss and validation metrics are fluctuating and no longer drop, but the maximum absolute weight of convolution layers continues to grow as the number of epoch increase. I am not sure what this means and what's the reason of this. Any ideas? Thanks!